# Why file uplaod does not work in solid.js?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, solid-js

I'm trying to make a simple multiple file upload using solid.js:

```
import { createSignal } from 'solid-js';

function App() {

  const [files, setFiles] = createSignal([]);

  function handleFileChange(event) {
    const selectedFiles = Array.from(event.target.files);
    setFiles(() => selectedFiles);
    selectedFiles.forEach(file => {
      console.log('Selected file:', file.name);
      console.log('File size:', file.size);
    });
  }

  async function uploadFiles() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const file of files()) {
      formData.append('file', file);
    } 

    // Send the file to the server using fetch or your preferred method
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8090/upload', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
        });
        console.log('File uploaded successfully');
      } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
      }
  }

 
  return (
    <div class={styles.App}>
        <div class={styles.item}>
      
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleFileChange} />
          <button onclick={uploadFiles}>Upload</button>
         </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the console I see the file names and their sizes:

```
Selected file: Track01.mp3
App.jsx:16 File size: 1650939
App.jsx:15 Selected file: Track02.mp3
App.jsx:16 File size: 1919269
App.jsx:15 Selected file: Track03.mp3
App.jsx:16 File size: 1338305
App.jsx:37 File uploaded successfully
```

But in the backend empty files is received:

```
files: []
```

And no file is saved in the destination path.

Then I read that createSignal does not allow arrays so I used `const [files, setFiles] = createStore([]);`  and  `for (const file of files)` respectively, buts still got the same result.

I've also tried `uploadFiles` snycronously, but without luck.

I'm new to solid.js. Just wondering why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: When I use `for (const file of files()`, I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: files is not iterable`. As far as I know you should invoke signal values in solid.js as they are treated as functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use `createStore` instead to keep track of upload files which accepts arrays directly contrary to `createSignle` which needs some trickery to do so.
Also had small problem in the backend to accept `file`. So I put the complete solid.js part here, as I could not find a working example myself:

```
import { createStore } from "solid-js/store";

function App() {

  const [files, setFiles] = createStore([]);
      function handleFileChange(event) {
        const selectedFiles = Array.from(event.target.files);
        setFiles( ()=> selectedFiles );
      }
    
      async function uploadFiles() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        for (const file of files) {
          formData.append('file', file);
    
        } 
    ``
           try {
            const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8090/upload', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData,
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
              console.log('response json:' , data); // Log the JSON response

            })
      
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
          }
     
      }

  return (
    <div class={styles.App}>
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleFileChange} />
          <button onclick={uploadFiles}>Upload</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use createStore, or a signal or an effect. You can make API calls directly, without all this additional cruft, and use a signals to track the status of that call so that you can show some feedback like a loading indicator, success or fail message.

Here you can find a detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74590574/7134134